# Doxygen / AppleDoc and Jenkins with Objective-C: where should the Doxygen / AppleDoc output live?

Tags: svn, continuous-integration, jenkins, doxygen, appledoc

Currently our team is using an SVN repository to manage our code on Server A, and changes to this repository trigger builds via Jenkins to be kicked off on Server B (so server B has a workspace that mirrors the repository on Server A).  Now, we wish to use a document generator like doxygen or appledoc, but I am unsure where the resulting documentation should live.

For example, Jenkins has a doxygen plug in; but since jenkins build commands only have access to the current workspace, this implies that the doxyfile to be accessed by the jenkins plugin must exist in the workspace, and thus be under source control (coming from the repository).  This is fine, but the resulting doxygen output should not really be source controlled, so does that mean the doxyfile should specify the output to be created somewhere on server B that is outside the workspace?

Furthermore, the overall goal would be to have docksets generated to be used seamlessly via our individual team member's Xcodes; but this seems like it would imply that the resulting dockets / makefiles etc do indeed need to be somehow part of the workspace (so that the individual team members can receive the results via SVN updates)...but this seems clunky, and I am not even sure if it is kosher to have folders/files created in a workspace that isn't coming from the SVN repository (since the workspace is meant to be a mirror).

Basically I am looking for a way to have documentation/docsets generated via Jenkins as a part of the build process, and for our individual team members to have Xcode option-click goodness to that resulting documentation (ideally without any manual steps required). Is this possible?

Thank you.

Comment: What is your build process exactly? You're using Ant, gnu-make, batch files?